# Finding the sum or mean of a 3d matrix with variable length in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, lstm

I have to do a averaging of 3d Tensor, where first dimension represents batch_size , second dimension reporesents max_length of sentence ( time axis ) in the batch and last dimension represents the embedding dimension. Those who are familiar with lstm, it is obtained by `tf.nn.emebedding_lookup`

For example:

```
Assume I have 3 sentences
[ [i, love, you,], [i, don't, love, you,], [i, always, love, you, so, much ]]
```

Here `batch_size = 3`, `max_length = 6` (3rd sentence ) and assume `embedding dimension = 100`. Normally, we will pad the first 2 sentences to match the max_length. Now, I need to average the word embeddings of each word. But, if I am using tf.reduce_sum, it will consider those padded vectors into consideration for the first two sentences, which is wrong. Is there an efficient way to do this in tensorflow.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution consists in passing the lengths of the original sentences (the ones without padding) to the model. In this way we can compute correct average embedding for each sentence.

In the preprocessing phase (when you generate your sentences), keep track of the length of each sentence. Suppose you generate the sentences with a `generate_batch` function, then:

```
batch = generate_batch(...)
batch_sentences = batch["sentences"] # [[i, love, you], [i, don't, love, you], ...]
batch_sentence_lengths = batch["sentence_lengths"] # [3, 4, ...]
```

Now you can feed the sentences and their lengths to the model:

```
with tf.Session(...) as sess:
    ...
    (loss, ) = sess.run(
        [loss],
        feed_dict = {
            sentences: batch_sentences,
            sentence_lengths: batch_sentence_lengths,
            ...
        })
    ...
```

You can use the length of each sentence in your model now:

```
...
# sentence_lengths is a sequence of integers: convert it to a sequence of floats
# sentence_lengths_float.shape = sentence_lengths.shape = (batch_size, )
sentence_lengths_float = tf.cast(sentence_lengths, tf.float32)

# Compute the sum of the embeddings for each sentence.
# If sentence_embeddings.shape = (batch_size, max_sentence_length, embedding_size), then sentence_axis = 1
# embeddings_sum_for_each_sentence.shape = (batch_size, embeddings_size)
embeddings_sum_for_each_sentence = tf.reduce_sum(sentence_embeddings, axis=sentence_axis)

# tf.div(a, b) divides each element of the last dimension of a by each element of b as long as the a.shape[-1] = n and b.shape = (1, n). See broadcasting in tf.
# If a is matrix, then tf.div divides each element of a row by the corresponding element in b. But we want a column-wise division, so we need to transpose a first.
# embeddings_avg_for_each_sentence_t.shape = (embedding_size, batch_size)
embeddings_avg_for_each_sentence_t = tf.div(tf.transpose(embeddings_sum_for_each_sentence), sentence_lengths_float)

# Finally we need to tranpose the result again.
# embeddings_avg_for_each_sentence.shape = (batch_size, embedding_size)
embeddings_avg_for_each_sentence = tf.tranpose(embeddings_avg_for_each_sentence_t)
...
```

Comment: Hi this is what I am doing now. But the problem here is, ```embeddings_sum_for_each_sentence = tf.reduce_sum(sentence_embeddings, axis=sentence_axis)``` here, it will add up the vectors for pad tokens right. If pad vector is zero, it is fine, but, what if I want to make my input embeddings trainable. Then padded vector ( even though it is zero initially, will get updated with some values and become a non-zero vector).

Comment: I see, I misunderstood the question. So the problem is that you don't want to the gradients to flow back to the padding embedding (the zero-filled embedding you are using for padding). A quick solution would be to multiply each row of the trainable embeddings matrix by 1, except for the padding embedding row which you multiply by 0. The result is a new matrix that is equal to the original matrix. The difference is that, during backpropagation, the gradients for the padding embedding row are multiplied by 0 now, so the it doesn't get updated.

Comment: yes, that is what the idea is, but how to do that inside tensorflow for each batch is what I am worried about

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is as follows. It is a bit complicated but works fine.

Some functions are obtained from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py . I recommend to do the imports same as above code. The main code is as follows

```
def _dynamic_average_loop(inputs,
                  initial_state,
                  parallel_iterations,
                  swap_memory,
                  sequence_length=None,
                  dtype=None):

        state = initial_state
        assert isinstance(parallel_iterations, int), "parallel_iterations must be int"
        flat_input = nest.flatten(inputs)
        embedding_dimension = tf.shape(inputs)[2]
        flat_output_size = [embedding_dimension]

        # Construct an initial output
        input_shape = array_ops.shape(flat_input[0])
        time_steps = input_shape[0]
        batch_size = _best_effort_input_batch_size(flat_input)

        inputs_got_shape = tuple(input_.get_shape().with_rank_at_least(3)
                               for input_ in flat_input)

        const_time_steps, const_batch_size = inputs_got_shape[0].as_list()[:2]

        for shape in inputs_got_shape:
            if not shape[2:].is_fully_defined():
              raise ValueError(
                  "Input size (depth of inputs) must be accessible via shape inference,"
                  " but saw value None.")
            got_time_steps = shape[0].value
            got_batch_size = shape[1].value
            if const_time_steps != got_time_steps:
              raise ValueError(
                  "Time steps is not the same for all the elements in the input in a "
                  "batch.")
            if const_batch_size != got_batch_size:
              raise ValueError(
        "Batch_size is not the same for all the elements in the input.")
        # Prepare dynamic conditional copying of state & output
        def _create_zero_arrays(size):
            size = _concat(batch_size, size)
            return array_ops.zeros(
                array_ops.stack(size), _infer_state_dtype(dtype, state))

        flat_zero_output = tuple(_create_zero_arrays(output)
                               for output in flat_output_size)
        zero_output = nest.pack_sequence_as(structure=embedding_dimension,
                                          flat_sequence=flat_zero_output)

        if sequence_length is not None:
            min_sequence_length = math_ops.reduce_min(sequence_length)
            max_sequence_length = math_ops.reduce_max(sequence_length)
        else:
            max_sequence_length = time_steps

        time = array_ops.constant(0, dtype=dtypes.int32, name="time")

        with ops.name_scope("dynamic_rnn") as scope:
            base_name = scope

        def _create_ta(name, element_shape, dtype):
            return tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(dtype=dtype,
                                                size=time_steps,
                                                element_shape=element_shape,
                                                tensor_array_name=base_name + name)

        in_graph_mode = not context.executing_eagerly()
        if in_graph_mode:
            output_ta = tuple(
                _create_ta(
                    "output_%d" % i,
                    element_shape=(tensor_shape.TensorShape([const_batch_size])
                                   .concatenate(
                                       _maybe_tensor_shape_from_tensor(out_size))),
                    dtype=_infer_state_dtype(dtype, state))
                for i, out_size in enumerate(flat_output_size))
            input_ta = tuple(
                _create_ta(
                    "input_%d" % i,
                    element_shape=flat_input_i.shape[1:],
                    dtype=flat_input_i.dtype)
                for i, flat_input_i in enumerate(flat_input))
            input_ta = tuple(ta.unstack(input_)
                             for ta, input_ in zip(input_ta, flat_input))
        else:
            output_ta = tuple([0 for _ in range(time_steps.numpy())]
                              for i in range(len(flat_output_size)))
            input_ta = flat_input


        def tf_average(A, B):

            return A+B 


        def _time_step(time, output_ta_t, state):

            input_t = tuple(ta.read(time) for ta in input_ta)
            # Restore some shape information
            for input_, shape in zip(input_t, inputs_got_shape):
                input_.set_shape(shape[1:])

            input_t = nest.pack_sequence_as(structure=inputs, flat_sequence=input_t)

            flat_state = nest.flatten(state)
            flat_zero_output = nest.flatten(zero_output)

            # Vector describing which batch entries are finished.
            copy_cond = time >= sequence_length



            def _copy_one_through(output, new_output):
                # Otherwise propagate the old or the new value.
                with ops.colocate_with(new_output):
                    return array_ops.where(copy_cond, output, new_output)

            the_average = tf_average(input_t, state)
            the_average_updated = _copy_one_through(zero_output, the_average)
            the_average_last_state = _copy_one_through(state, the_average)

            for output, flat_output in zip([the_average_updated], flat_zero_output):
                output.set_shape(flat_output.get_shape())

            final_output = nest.pack_sequence_as(structure=zero_output, flat_sequence=[the_average_updated])
            output_ta_t = tuple(ta.write(time, out) for ta, out in zip(output_ta_t, [final_output]))
            return (time + 1, output_ta_t, the_average_last_state)


        if in_graph_mode:
            # Make sure that we run at least 1 step, if necessary, to ensure
            # the TensorArrays pick up the dynamic shape.
            loop_bound = math_ops.minimum(
                time_steps, math_ops.maximum(1, max_sequence_length))
        else:
        # Using max_sequence_length isn't currently supported in the Eager branch.
            loop_bound = time_steps

        _, output_final_ta, final_state = control_flow_ops.while_loop(
              cond=lambda time, *_: time < loop_bound,
              body=_time_step,
              loop_vars=(time, output_ta, state),
              parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations,
              maximum_iterations=time_steps,
             swap_memory=swap_memory)

        final_outputs = tuple(ta.stack() for ta in output_final_ta)
            # Restore some shape information
        for output, output_size in zip(final_outputs, flat_output_size):
            shape = _concat(
              [const_time_steps, const_batch_size], output_size, static=True)
            output.set_shape(shape)

        final_outputs = nest.pack_sequence_as(structure=embedding_dimension,
                                              flat_sequence=final_outputs)

        return final_outputs , final_state



def dynamic_average(inputs, sequence_length=None, initial_state=None,
            dtype=None, parallel_iterations=None, swap_memory=False,
            time_major=False, scope=None):

        with vs.variable_scope(scope or "rnn") as varscope:
        # Create a new scope in which the caching device is either
        # determined by the parent scope, or is set to place the cached
        # Variable using the same placement as for the rest of the RNN.
            if _should_cache():
              if varscope.caching_device is None:
                varscope.set_caching_device(lambda op: op.device)

            # By default, time_major==False and inputs are batch-major: shaped
            #   [batch, time, depth]
            # For internal calculations, we transpose to [time, batch, depth]
        flat_input = nest.flatten(inputs)
        embedding_dimension = tf.shape(inputs)[2]

        if not time_major:
          # (B,T,D) => (T,B,D)
          flat_input = [ops.convert_to_tensor(input_) for input_ in flat_input]
          flat_input = tuple(_transpose_batch_time(input_) for input_ in flat_input)

        parallel_iterations = parallel_iterations or 32
        if sequence_length is not None:
          sequence_length = math_ops.to_int32(sequence_length)
          if sequence_length.get_shape().ndims not in (None, 1):
            raise ValueError(
                "sequence_length must be a vector of length batch_size, "
                "but saw shape: %s" % sequence_length.get_shape())
          sequence_length = array_ops.identity(  # Just to find it in the graph.
              sequence_length, name="sequence_length")

        batch_size = _best_effort_input_batch_size(flat_input)

        state = tf.zeros(shape=(batch_size, embedding_dimension))

        def _assert_has_shape(x, shape):
          x_shape = array_ops.shape(x)
          packed_shape = array_ops.stack(shape)
          return control_flow_ops.Assert(
              math_ops.reduce_all(math_ops.equal(x_shape, packed_shape)),
              ["Expected shape for Tensor %s is " % x.name,
               packed_shape, " but saw shape: ", x_shape])

        if not context.executing_eagerly() and sequence_length is not None:
          # Perform some shape validation
          with ops.control_dependencies(
              [_assert_has_shape(sequence_length, [batch_size])]):
            sequence_length = array_ops.identity(
                sequence_length, name="CheckSeqLen")

        inputs = nest.pack_sequence_as(structure=inputs, flat_sequence=flat_input)

        (outputs, final_state) = _dynamic_average_loop(
            inputs,
            state,
            parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations,
            swap_memory=swap_memory,
            sequence_length=sequence_length,
    dtype=dtype)

        if not time_major:
            outputs = nest.map_structure(_transpose_batch_time, outputs)
        return outputs, final_state
```

This is the main code. So to find the sum of a 3D matrix, of variable length as in RNN, we can test it as follows

```
    tf.reset_default_graph()

    the_inputs = np.random.uniform(-1,1,(30,50,111)).astype(np.float32)
    the_length = np.random.randint(50, size=30)
    the_input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(the_inputs)
    the_length_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(the_length)

    outputs, final_state = dynamic_average(inputs=the_input_tensor, 
sequence_length=the_length_tensor)

    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    outputs_result , final_state_result = sess.run((outputs, final_state))

    print("Testing")
    for index in range(len(the_inputs)):

        print(the_inputs[index,:,:][:the_length[index]].sum(axis=0) == final_state_result[index])
    print('------------------------------------------------------------------')
```